# get_posts query caching?

Tags: wp-query, get-posts, cache

I'm using get_posts outside of the Wordpress theme and it's pulling up posts which used to have meta "featured_user" = on and none of the new post which has meta "featured_user" = on. This behavior doesn't happen when I use the same code within the theme. Is there some sort of caching going on?

```
require_once("wp-blog-header.php");

$query_args = array(

    'post_type' => 'fre_profile' ,
    'post_status' => 'publish' ,
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'meta_query' =>  array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'featured_user',
            'value'   => 'on',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
    'orderby'  => 'rand'
);

$loop = get_posts( $query_args);
```

Comment: Yes, posts get cached. But if you use the WordPress functions to insert a new post, this should not be a problem. Where do you exactly use get_posts? How do you insert posts? All in one HTTP-query?

Comment: I'm using this for a dynamic HTML 5 ad that loads within an iframe on the theme. None of the actual post is displayed however, some of the post meta is shown.